# React not render Li elements

Tags: javascript, list, reactjs

Try to render list of elements, but browser return me something like that.
In tutorial that I watch, returns "li" elements, but I don't no why it returns
this

```
<div id="root">
    <div data-reactroot="">
       <ul>
          <contact name="vasya"></contact>
          <contact name="Petya"></contact>
          <contact name="Killa"></contact>
          <contact name="Pedro"></contact>
       </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

Need to return "li" elements

Im new in React, so haven't any idea why it's happens
My code

```
var contacts = [
    {
    id: 1,
    name: "vasya",
    phone: "0989893"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Petya",
        phone: "0986666"
    },
    {
        id: 31,
        name: "Killa",
        phone: "09833333"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Pedro",
        phone: "09833434"
    },
]

var contact = React.createClass({
    render: function () {

        return(
            <li> {this.props.name}</li>
              );

    }
});

var ContactList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {
                    contacts.map(function (el) {
                        return <contact key={el.id} name={el.name}/>;
                    })
                }
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(

        <ContactList />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your component must start with capital later.**

In JSX, lower-case tag names are considered to be HTML tags.

```
var Contact = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (<li> {this.props.name} </li>);
    }
});
```

and then render like

```
<Contact {...props} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Component name have to be `<Contact />` not `<contact />`.

```js
var contacts = [
    { id: 1, name: "vasya", phone: "0989893" },
    { id: 2, name: "Petya", phone: "0986666" },
    { id: 31, name: "Killa", phone: "09833333" },
    { id: 4, name: "Pedro", phone: "09833434" },
]

var Contact = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <li> {this.props.name}</li>
    );
  }
});

var ContactList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {
            contacts.map(function (el) {
              return <Contact key={el.id} name={el.name}/>;
            })
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <ContactList />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

On React site there is explanation about difference between elements and components - [`React Components, Elements, and Instances`](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html)